# Confused of lists brackets and parentheses & Operator before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Few things really confuse me, First is in lists what is the difference between

list1 = [100,200,300]
And, 
list3 = [(1,1), (2,4), (3,)]

Of course, I obviously see the visual difference but I don't get what is the difference beside the parentheses.

Also what does what mean? And what does it actually do ?
When we use the operator like that
list += 1
or
list -= 1
Totally confused. 
Searched a lot but seems like I am searching for wrong content.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just read about *lists* and **tuples** in Python Tutorial.

Comment: Just search for *tuples* and *lists*. Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm).

Comment: @amrX [Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), [more on Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), [Tuples and all basic types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)

Comment: please clear the theory before coding, else you will waste lots of time on this kind of question.

Comment: @amrX no body here is being offensive, we just want people *learn to learn*. You could [read this post so you get the idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182380/237562).

Comment: @Christian, Now it make a lot of sense, wish someone sent me that earlier, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list of three numbers:

```
list1 = [100,200,300]
```

This is a list of three [tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

```
list3 = [(1,1), (2,4), (3,)]
```

A tuple is an immutable (can't be changed without destroying and creating a new one) collection of ordered items, that are indexed by key.

This doesn't do anything except raise an error, because you cannot add a number to a list:

```
>>> i = [1,2,3]
>>> i += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

If you use two types that can be added together, then `+=` adds the value on the right, to the value pointed to by the name on the left:

```
>>> i = 1
>>> i += 1
>>> i
2
```

It is the same as doing this:

```
>>> i = 1
>>> i = i + 1
>>> i
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1 = [100,200,300]
>>> list3 = [(1,1), (2,4), (3,)]

>>> for item in list1:
...     print("{}: {}".format(repr(item), type(item)))
... 
100: <type 'int'>
200: <type 'int'>
300: <type 'int'>

>>> for item in list3:
...     print("{}: {}".format(repr(item), type(item)))
... 
(1, 1): <type 'tuple'>
(2, 4): <type 'tuple'>
(3,): <type 'tuple'>
```

---

```
list += 1
```

or

```
list -= 1
```

Will cause an exception - eg.

```
>>> list += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'type' and 'int'
```

unless someone has shadowed the builtin with their own variable

```
>>> list = 999
>>> list += 1
>>> list
1000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 list1=[100,200,300] ==> is a list and element in this list is mutable means you can change the value of element by accessing any index in list, ex: list1[1]=400

 list3 = [(1,1), (2,4), (3,)] ==> is a list of tubles; tuples in python represented by (). This indicates elements in tuples can't be changed. In list3, you access each tuples by using it's index; for ex list3[0] returns (1,1) which is list element. list3[0][0] returns 1 which is tuple element. The difference here is that you cannot assign like list3[0][0] = 2.
```

You can read more at [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)!